# in PHP OOP Which is better: keep values in Variable or object? do I need to return something in a Method?

Tags: php, oop

I am a beginner in PHP OOP.

I was wondering what is the best practice in PHP OOP and classes. Keep values in a Variables ($var) or keep them in the object ($this->var).
As you can see in below code I set the variables ($this->var) in methods and ,therefore, do not need to return anything from that method.

Is this a correct way of doing it or do I need to return somthing from method? and pass that value to the next method?
Below is a simple curl class for API that extracts a clients email address by using a code.
Pay specific attention to extract_ib_email() Method, no variable is passed to functions (Methods). Is this correct and is there a better way of doing it please?

```
//Parent Class
class CurlRequest
{

  /* get the data from a URL */
  protected function curl_get_data() {

    $ch = curl_init();
    //$timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, $this->curloptVERBOSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->curloptSSLVERIFYPEER);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->curlURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $this->curloptRETURNTRANSFER);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($data === FALSE) {
        printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
        htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
    }
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
    //var_dump($data);
    curl_close($ch);
    $this->data = $data;
    return $data;
  }
}
class GetIBEmail extends CurlRequest
{
  private $ibRef;

  function __construct($ibRef)
  {
    // Set Variables
    $this->baseURL                = 'https://www.example.com/api/iel/';
    $this->ibRef                  = $ibRef;
    //$this->ibCode                 = $ibCode;

    //set curl options for this request specifically
    $this->timeout                = $timeout = 5;
    $this->curloptVERBOSE         = $curlopt_VERBOSE = true;
    $this->curloptSSLVERIFYPEER   = $curlopt_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false;
    $this->curloptRETURNTRANSFER  = $curlopt_RETURNTRANSFER = 1;
  }

  // IB Code form is like ib_xxx need to get the last 3 letters
  private function getIBCode(){
    $ibRefBits = explode('_', $this->ibRef);
    $this->ibCode = $ibRefBits[1];
    //return $this->ibCode;
  }

  //construct the curl url using the IB code
  private function construct_ib_curl_url(){

    //$url = 'https://www.example.com/api/iel/xxx';
    //$url = $this->baseURL . $this->ibCode;
    $this->curlURL = $this->baseURL . $this->ibCode;
    //return $url;
  }

  // extract email from returned curl response
  public function extract_ib_email() {
    $this->getIBCode();
    $this->construct_ib_curl_url();
    $this->curl_get_data(); 


    $resArr = array();
    $resArr = json_decode($this->data);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

    $ib_email = $resArr[0]->email;
    $this->ib_email = $ib_email;
    return $ib_email;
  }
}
//Set ibCode
$ibCode   = 'ib_xxx'; //$_SESSION['ib_code'];
$ibEmail = new GetIBEmail($ibCode); //pass value to the construct function
echo '<br>' . $ibEmail->extract_ib_email() . '<br>';
```

Comment: It's about global properties. Use them if: 1) they are really property and 2) you need the same property in different methods of your class. For example: a user object will have a name and age property. Personally, I love returns, because the testibility of the method.

Comment: In OOP `GetIBEmail ` would never extend `CurlRequest`, but it would ather be passed in as a dependency.

Comment: PeeHaa, what do you mean? do you mean i should have put GetIBEmail in the CurlRequest Class? You see I make a lot of curl requests (5 may be more) within the application with each being different in structure of data returned and also different option set ups so rathere than repeating myself 5 times in curl request I have created a parent class, something like "Abstract Class". if this is not what you meant could you explain a bit more please.